# Mitsubishi lancer not starting

Tags: engine, mitsubishi, timing-belt, lancer

I have an 03 lancer which stalled on my way home and won't start. I hear something spinning when I attempt to start it, but it doesn't sound like it normally would. Almost as if something is spinning and not catching. I looked under the hood while someone tried to start it and saw the alternator belt moving. I took the cover for the timing belt off and had them try to start it again, but that wasn't moving. The belt looks ok from the top half but I can't see the bottom half because of the bottom cover.

1. Is my engine toast due to the amount of times I tried to start it while the timing belt wasn't moving?
2. My car is putting out a code for the cam shaft position sensor. Is that confirming my engine is done for?
3. This is the only car I ever owned. I was thinking of getting a truck, but would like to find out if its worth fixing this car and selling it, or just selling it as is (if the engine is bad)?

Comment: You will need to replace the timing belt before you can diagnose further, what engine do you have?

Comment: This was copied and pasted from autozones site: 2003 Mitsubishi Lancer 2.0L FI SOHC 4cyl. About a month ago, I got pricing for replacing the timing belt and got quotes from $600-$900. If I have to pay that much just to replace the belt with the chance that the engine is bad anyways, I'll probably just get rid of the car.